# How to insert a record and return the newly created ID using a single SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using an SqlCommand object to insert a record into a table with an autogenerated primary key. How can I write the command text so that I get the newly created ID when I use the ExecuteScalar() method?

Comment: If you are using a Guid, see my answer.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(val1, val2, val3 ...) 
VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3...);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Don't forget the semicolons at the end of each statement.

Comment: rather than using the scope_identity(), you could just use the output clause - INSERT INTO YourTable(val1, val2, val3 ...) output inserted.$identity VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3...);

Comment: No, you can't. If your table has triggers on it you'll get this error: The target table 'Site' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Answer (score 26):

Add the following line to the end of the Sql Query...

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

And then use the ExecuteScalar method on the SqlCommand object...

```
var rowCount = command.ExecuteScalar()
```

Answer (score 16):

```
insert into Yourtable()  
values()  
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I just ran a test and verified that the semi-colons are optional using SQL Server 2005 SP2, and .Net 3.5

Comment: Don't know about the downvote, but SET NOCOUNT ON is _not_ necessary for this to work.  Could be the missing semi-colon.

Comment: in ADO 6.0 the set no count would be required if your pulling back a recordset hence my it might;-). I just a ran test and you don't need the semi-colons and you don't need set nocount

Answer (score 5):

Add an output parameter to the command object and then set the value to the new ID in the stored procedure.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
@ID AS INT OUTPUT

[Insert Command]

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

**.NET:**

```
cmd.CommandText = "stored_procedure";

SqlParameter pID = new SqlParameter("ID", DBType.Int32, 4);

pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.ExecuteScalar();

int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["ID"].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after your insert stmt, use

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS bigint) ---- incase you have a return result as int64
```

This will return the column created id/identity.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use @@IDENTITY, however simple it may seem.  It can return incorrect values.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

appears to be the obvious choice.

Answer (score 2):

Although I like [Dave Markle's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330707/how-to-insert-a-record-and-return-the-newly-created-id-using-a-single-sqlcommand#330728) answer, ( and I see you did too, since you marked it as your answer ), that method can fail if you have triggers on your database, that audit CUD operations, and your audit table has an IDENTITY column. It would return the value of the Audit table's identity, not the table you just inserted into, since the audit table actualy happen after.

In that case, a more generic method can be used that will work in both cases, regardless of any auditing. Its a bit more wordy, but you get what you pay for.

example:

```
@"DECLARE @tmp AS TABLE ( id int )
                    INSERT INTO case
                    (
                        caseID,
                        partID,
                        serialNumber,
                        hardware,
                        software,
                        firmware
                    )
                    OUTPUT Inserted.ID into @tmp
                    VALUES
                    (
                        @caseID,
                        @partItemID,
                        @serialNumber,
                        @hardware,
                        @software,
                        @firmware
                    )
                Select ID from @tmp" )
```

Comment: Scope_identity will not fail if you have triggers, it is @@identity that will fail.

Comment: @Russ Your answer helped me when dealing with an error caused by SyncFramework triggers- 'The target table 'dbo.table' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.'  I am using a GUID for my PK and have no IDENTITY column.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your id is a Guid, then I found this solution to be best:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (val1, val2, val3) 
OUTPUT inserted.id 
VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3)
```

Thanks @Scott Ivey

Full demo:

```
    internal static Guid InsertNote(Note note)
    {
            Guid id;

            using (
                var connection =
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (
                    var command =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "INSERT INTO Notes ([Title],[Text]) " +
                            "OUTPUT inserted.id " +
                            $"VALUES ('{title}','{text}');", connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    id = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
                }
                connection.Close();
            }

            return id;
    }
```

I would recommend using a Stored Procedure, but this is for unit testing our repository.

Comment: Yes! Finally, after searching for almost an hour, an answer that shows how to get the OUTPUT value in C# for a GUID.

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of the [Whirlpool](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/699785.html):

> If you're using MS SQL you can use "SELECT @@IDENTITY as Value" after your insert to get the last ID generated

and:

> `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY` return the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. However, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the value only within the current scope; `@@IDENTITY` is not limited to a specific scope.

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, you should always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, not `@@IDENTITY`.

Comment: If you have any triggers @@Identity can return the wrong value

Comment: Always use SCOPE_IDENTITY. Not @@Identity.