# SQL Server and C#: get last inserted id

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public static void CreateSocialGroup(string FBUID)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) VALUES (@FBUID); SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FBUID", FBUID);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? And how do i get LastID in to a variable? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get last inserted id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

Answer (score 26):

OUTPUT clause?

```
string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) 
                OUTPUT INSERTED.IDCol  --use real column here
                VALUES (@FBUID)";
...
int lastId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Works, but i get 2 rows inserted, why?

Comment: @Johan: it is being called twice somewhere. The SQL given inserts one row only.

Comment: it might be better to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() rather than OUTPUT as OUTPUT will give you errors in case you have triggers set on the table (as stated on [this question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330707/how-to-insert-a-record-and-return-the-newly-created-id-using-a-single-sqlcommand))

Answer (score 10):

You can use ExecuteScalar to get the last value from a Sqlcommand.

The scope_identity() function is safer than @@identity.

Answer (score 8):

If your server supports the [`OUTPUT clause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) you could try it with this one:

```
public static void CreateSocialGroup(string FBUID)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) OUTPUT INSERTED.IDENTITYCOL VALUES (@FBUID)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FBUID", FBUID);

        connection.Open();
        var _id = command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: INSERTED.IDENTITYCOL doesn't work in SQL Azure. However if your identity column is named for example 'ID' then INSERTED.ID works!

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would re-write your code to use Parameters.  You could either use an `InputOutput` parameter or an `Output` Parameter.  However, using a Return Value in your SQL would also work.

Full examples on this [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99.aspx).

I would also use `Scope_Identity()` rather than `@@Identity` this will ensure that you will reveice the ID that relates to the current transaction.  Details on [Scope_Identity can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

U can try ExecuteScalar for getting the LastID value.

Comment: Works, but i get 2 rows inserted, why?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use a stored procedure to do this. You can give it an [`OUTPUT`](http://www.programmingado.net/a-145/Retrieving-SQL-Server-stored-procedure-output-parameters.aspx) parameter which you can use to return the id value back to your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into table values (1,2,3); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);

lastRecord = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `Stored Procedure` only for the queries and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get max value.

Comment: This is parameterised already. The `Parameters.AddWithValue` tells us this.

Comment: While writing the queries and sending to network can produce congestion. Like OP wrote "string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) VALUES (@FBUID); SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastID";
" This is not a good practice. This should be in stored procedure

Comment: do you have an authoritative reference to describe that behaviour? A stored proc call is still sent over the network too.

Comment: Thank you for 30 downvotes: you really shouldn't post in public if you can't deal with criiticsm. Note: your rep profile gives this downvoting away so don't deny it... FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756

Answer (score -16):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select max(id) from SocialGroup ", connection);
int lastId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: MAX(id) is probably not the right way. SCOPE_IDENTITY() as suggested elsewhere is better.

Comment: -1 for possibly the worst answer I've seen to this common questions

Comment: -1 Also. Just in case you are unsure of the problem a concurrent transaction could perform an insert and thus your select returns the wrong result.