# 2 rows inserted instead of 1 when using @@IDENTITY / scope_identity()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) VALUES (@FBUID); SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FBUID", FBUID);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int lastID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

    }
```

Without the

```
SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
```

One row is inserted. But since I need the ID from the created row im using scope_identity. However, when I use this, 2 rows are created instead of one.

Did I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the code you've posted is that you run 2 times the same query... one with **ExecuteNonQuery();** and the last with **(int)command.ExecuteScalar();**

If you try to use only the executeScalar i think you have the result's you want....

Try and hope this helps...

If you want you can use Parameter to retrieve the Identity, like they do in this [Article](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you would use [gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109634/mssql-c-get-last-inserted-id/6109821#6109821) or [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109634/mssql-c-get-last-inserted-id/6109866#6109866) answer from your first question, the problem shouldn't occur.

Comment: Tried the OUTPUT, same result though.

Comment: Never mind, forgot to remove the command.ExecuteNonQuery();. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))     
    {         
    string query = "INSERT INTO SocialGroup (created_by_fbuid) VALUES (@FBUID);";         
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);            
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FBUID", FBUID);         
     connection.Open();         
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     query = "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";     
     command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);                   
    int lastID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();      
    }
```