# Visual C# Winforms Database Problem

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010, variables

I am having a problem with my database problem.. errr..

```
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerName)
VALUES ('Joe Schmoe'); LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I used something like that in my winform so this statement:

```
  INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerName)
  VALUES ('Joe Schmoe'); LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

-**shows me the last inserted id in my customer column**

I want to store the value that I can get into a variable so that whenever I put a value to its child table (foreign key) I will use what value that I have stored in my variable to my insert statement.

How can I store it in a variable or a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at below examples. Cannot give the exact SQL without knowing your database.

[SQL Server and C#: get last inserted id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109634/sql-server-and-c-get-last-inserted-id)

[Get inserted id.](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/699785)

[How to get last inserted id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228780/how-to-get-last-inserted-id)

[Getting the identity of the most recently added record](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)

[C# Code Snippet - Get Identity Column Value from SQL Server](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Get-Identity-Column-Value-from-SQL-Server.html)

**EDIT**

If it is MySQL Database, you could use [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) built in function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405910/get-the-id-of-inserted-row-using-c) is a code sample.