# Getting the primary key for an inserted value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a simple table with 2 columns - name and the primary key, id. When I insert a value, I wish to be able to retrieve the value straight away in my code.

So I have :

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES (@0)",name);
```

The id column is not automatically populated and the row is stored.

So how can I `db.Query();` for this value when the name is not unique? Is this possible?

An interesting problem, I think :)

Comment: Is your id column set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert a record and return the newly created ID using a single SqlCommand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330707/how-to-insert-a-record-and-return-the-newly-created-id-using-a-single-sqlcommand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a part to your insert that returns the identity using [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES (@0); SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

Update: As noted in comments since `@@IDENTITY` works globally you should actually use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) instead to limit to the current scope:

```
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES (@0); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Then you can retrieve the primary key / identity by executing your insert with `ExecuteScalar()` and grabbing the result.

Comment: I agree, but use IDENTITY_SCOPE as it is better suited for the problem at hand.  
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES (@0); SELECT @@IDENTITY;

Comment: @Roberto ... I think you mean SCOPE_IDENTITY() :-)

Comment: @RobertoHernandez: You are correct, that would be a better approach, updated answer

Comment: @BrokenGlass Thanks very much for this answer. For anyone using WebMatrix; the solution is to call QueryValue() rather than ExecuteScalar() :)

Comment: @ChrisJ :) Yes, that is what I meant!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`  baring some unusual circumstance. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES (@0); SELECT Scope_Identity();
```

Why not @@identity?  because it can be wrong in many scenarios.  [MSDN docs describe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) it as:

> @@IDENTITY, SCOPE_IDENTITY, and IDENT_CURRENT are similar functions in
>   that they return the last value inserted into the IDENTITY column of a
>   table.
>
> @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last identity value
>   generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns the value only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not
>   limited to a specific scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use `db.ExecuteScalar` and add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end of your SQL statement to retrieve the primary key.