# Insert record in two tables with identity field value from first table

Tags: sql-server

How can we insert record in two tables in same stored Procedure in SQL Server. I need just inserted ID field from first table to insert it as reference to second table. As in multi user environment we will have concurrent inserts.

Comment: Take a look at `scope_identity()` function.

Comment: You also can use output clause which can work with bulk inserts as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting to one table, insert the ID to second table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760439/inserting-to-one-table-insert-the-id-to-second-table)

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @id INT

    INSERT INTO tbl1
    VALUES (..)

    SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO tbl2
    VALUES (@id)

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
begin tran
Declare @tbl table (id int)

insert into t11
output inserted.* into @tbl
select 1


insert into t2
select * from @tbl
commit
```