# How do I input multiple values into database tables with composite tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

[Database ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSrYO.png)

Hey guys, I'm having some trouble inserting my survey data to a database that has a bunch of composite tables with foreign+primary key relationships. You can see what the relationship looks like from the ERDiagram above (I know I've messed up the M:M relationships, but if you can overlook that you can see the relationships from the PK and FK).

Here is my C# code from a WebFormApplication:

```
int GID, AID, SID, ISP =0;
        string homeSub, homePC, workSub, workPC, email ="";
        List<int> CarMakes = new List<int>();
        List<int> Banks = new List<int>();
        List<int> addService = new List<int>();
        List<int> addISP = new List<int>();

        GID = rblGender.SelectedIndex+1;
        AID = ddlAge.SelectedIndex+1;
        SID = ddlState.SelectedIndex + 1;
        ISP = ddlISP.SelectedIndex + 1;

        homeSub = tbxHomeSuburb.Text;
        homePC = tbxHomePostCode.Text;
        workSub = tbxWorkSuburb.Text;
        workPC = tbxWorkPostcode.Text;
        email = tbxEmailAdd.Text;

        //Validation stuff here:

        //if empty blah blah

        SqlConnection myConnection;
        SqlCommand queryCommand;
//This string is correct, I have used it plenty of times to Databind data to the form            
String myConnectionString = "Login Creditials are hidden";

        myConnection = new SqlConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        //I need one command to insert all survey data into their respective tables with the RID as a FK to connect all the data back to that respondent
        String sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO RESPONDENT (email, home_postcode, home_suburb, work_postcode, work_suburb) VALUES ('"+email+"','"+homePC+"','"+homeSub+"','"+workPC+"','"+workSub+"');";

        queryCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, myConnection);

        // Perform connect
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dataReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

This is triggered on a button click event if that information is useful at all. Thank you in advance if anyone can help solve this!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: There's no particular error. I'm just wondering how I would go about inserting all of the data I'm collection from the survey into separate tables all at once.

Comment: Starting with the parent tables for every parent-child relationship, insert the data one table at a time.

Comment: Okay now I seem to be getting an error: 

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Gender_Respond". The conflict occurred in database "DB_9AB8B7_DDA5041", table "dbo.GENDER", column 'GID'.

Comment: For foreign keys in the child table, the corresponding primary key has to pre-exist in the parent table.

Comment: Ahh the problem seems to be originating from getting the SelectedIndex of the dropdown list. For some reason the SelectedIndex is always returning -1. And the SelectedIndex of all the CheckBoxList and RadioButtonList are all coming back as 0...

Answer (score 0):

1. You insert into the `respond` table.
2. Get the created autonumeric `RID` [**Here Is How**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330707/how-to-insert-a-record-and-return-the-newly-created-id-using-a-single-sqlcommand)
3. Insert into the other table using `RID` doing muliples insert one by one.

Comment: Ahh the autonumeric RID is where I was getting stuck. So using SCOPE_IDENTITY on the RESPONDENT table will return me the previously auto-incremented RID?

Comment: Yes, but you do `INSERT` and `SELECT` in one `SqlCommand` as  example show